# "changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect" in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7-beta6

I am receiving this warning in the debugger console when I launch my app on **iPad Xcode 7 beta 6**. There was no such warning till **Xcode 6**. I don't understand why it may have come and that too, only on iPad.

According to [an Apple forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13716) it could be a bug from Apple's side. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the same bug occured to me when launching a custom keyboard on the iPad

Comment: Has this been resolved in the GM ?

Comment: No I am still getting the warnings in GM

Comment: I have this warning when presenting modal `UIActivityViewController.`

Comment: Just migrated to Xcode 7 and I have the same warning as soon as a UITextView becomes first responder...

Comment: I have this pop-up when a `UITextField` has to `becomeFirstResponder`, the time the textField needs to actually becomeFirstResponder is also increased significantly.

Comment: Same issue. It only seems to appear on the iPad for me. And yes the lag for the keyboard to become first responder is ridiculously long. It doesn't even happen some times.

Comment: Having same problem when presenting `UIActivityViewController`.  Only occurs on iOS9 iPads.  iOS8 is fine and iPhones are fine.

Comment: @StudentX Have you solved this problem?

Comment: No unfortunately not.. plus I'm looking into other issues my application has, so I'm occupied with those..

Comment: Any luck solving this ? , I'm on Xcode 7 and it only occurs on iPad when presenting the keyboard. I'm not using any external libraries.

Comment: See [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775575/catransformlayer-0x14fea3710-changing-property-maskstobounds-in-transform-o) - looks like a bug and logged with Apple as such.

Comment: I've got the same problem, only 3x... and I can't see what's causing it... will have to spend some time on it when I have some time...  :-{

Comment: If you do not interact using the keyboard (i.e, if you use the trackpad or the mouse only), this warning is not happening.

Was using Cmd+Q to quit the simulator from a particular ViewController and this happened whenever i was doing it. Instead, i tried with the Simulator->Quit option using mouse and this did not show up. Its a bug.

Answer (score 24):

In order to get rid of this error un check clip to bounds option and put scale to fill to view to all view,UIStackView you have used in your project.

Comment: Verified. I am on Version 9.2 (9C40b) and this was the cause for me. Nice one

Comment: Thanks, uncheck `Clip to Bounds` from `UIStackView` removed the warnings

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug in iOS, and still exists in the latest version, iOS 9.1. If you're reading this, please do us all a favor and file a bug report with Apple.

You may duplicate my radar (id: 23666339), which can be viewed on Open Radar here: [https://openradar.appspot.com/23666339](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4947771354251264)

The bug causes the keyboard to take forever to appear, and exists only on iPad as well as the iPad simulators.

**UPDATE:** This issue has been resolved as of iOS 9.2 (13C75).

Comment: thank you for validating me on this - thought it was a problem with our app!

Comment: I have noted that this still exists on 9.3 -

Answer (score 9):

It could happen because you changed drawing attribute of the StackView:

[image]

when I set clips to bounds to true I get this warning

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is facing this issue because of a UIStackView in iOS 14, please check out this article:

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stack-view-background-color-in-ios-14/

Long story short:

In iOS 14, UIStackView has changed from using a CATransformLayer to using a CALayer. I saw this first mentioned by Renaud Lienhart (@layoutsubviews) and then confirmed by David Duncan (@rincewindsama). This change is not (yet) mentioned in any release note or documentation (bug report FB8363575).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Warning**  -> <CATransformLayer: 0x600000946e40> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect

**Solution = Simply uncheck the clip to bound from UIstackview box.**

[image]