# <CATransformLayer: 0x14fea3710> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer, xcode7

I am getting this warning report in xCode 7.0

This happens when i am using `MBProgress` HUD in my project. How to deal with this warning?

I saw ["changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect" in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456727/changing-property-maskstobounds-in-transform-only-layer-will-have-no-effect-x) but no use...

Comment: I have this pop-up when a UITextField has to becomeFirstResponder, the time the textField needs to actually becomeFirstResponder is also increased significantly.

Comment: same here I'm also using MBProgress HUD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case this must be related to a keyboard bug.  All I have to do is launch an iPad Simulator, and press (CommandKey).

Three errors:

```
2015-09-29 19:40:47.251 ArchKit[12577:338772] <CATransformLayer: 0x7ff592f12ca0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-09-29 19:40:47.252 ArchKit[12577:338772] <CATransformLayer: 0x7ff592d1a2f0> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2015-09-29 19:40:47.252 ArchKit[12577:338772] <CATransformLayer: 0x7ff592f25d30> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

Just by pressing the (CommandKey).

Even if I make a starter project with Sprite Kit for instance.  So this is a bug.

Comment: So did you file a bug?

Comment: No I did not, I actually thought someone else did.

Comment: Duped as 23069576, and submitted to open radar https://openradar.appspot.com/23069576. So you can use this id to file a duplicate with QuickRadar.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to ignore the warning.

In my case I have a little prototype project where I analyze keyboard avoidance. I don't use any animation, and I don't directly change layer properties which would give a reason for the warning. I only change UIScrollView offsets, insets and the like. Yet the warning shows up, so I assume it is something which needs to be taken care of in the SDK. (Or simulator?)